# How to create a DataFrame from a text file in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I have a text file on HDFS and I want to convert it to a Data Frame in Spark.

I am using the Spark Context to load the file and then try to generate individual columns from that file.

```
val myFile = sc.textFile("file.txt")
val myFile1 = myFile.map(x=>x.split(";"))
```

After doing this, I am trying the following operation.

```
myFile1.toDF()
```

I am getting an issues since the elements in myFile1 RDD are now array type.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Update** - as of **Spark 1.6**, you can simply use the built-in csv data source:

```
spark: SparkSession = // create the Spark Session
val df = spark.read.csv("file.txt")
```

You can also use various options to control the CSV parsing, e.g.:

```
val df = spark.read.option("header", "false").csv("file.txt")
```

**For Spark version < 1.6**:
The easiest way is to use [spark-csv](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv) - include it in your dependencies and follow the README, it allows setting a custom delimiter (`;`), can read CSV headers (if you have them), and it can infer the schema *types* (with the cost of an extra scan of the data).

Alternatively, if you know the schema you can create a case-class that represents it and map your RDD elements into instances of this class before transforming into a DataFrame, e.g.:

```
case class Record(id: Int, name: String)

val myFile1 = myFile.map(x=>x.split(";")).map {
  case Array(id, name) => Record(id.toInt, name)
} 

myFile1.toDF() // DataFrame will have columns "id" and "name"
```

Answer (score 11):

I have given different ways to create DataFrame from text file

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName(appName).setMaster("local")
val sc = SparkContext(conf)
```

### raw text file

```
val file = sc.textFile("C:\\vikas\\spark\\Interview\\text.txt")
val fileToDf = file.map(_.split(",")).map{case Array(a,b,c) => 
(a,b.toInt,c)}.toDF("name","age","city")
fileToDf.foreach(println(_))
```

### spark session without schema

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
val sparkSess = 
SparkSession.builder().appName("SparkSessionZipsExample")
.config(conf).getOrCreate()

val df = sparkSess.read.option("header", 
"false").csv("C:\\vikas\\spark\\Interview\\text.txt")
df.show()
```

### spark session with schema

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
val schemaString = "name age city"
val fields = schemaString.split(" ").map(fieldName => StructField(fieldName, 
StringType, nullable=true))
val schema = StructType(fields)

val dfWithSchema = sparkSess.read.option("header", 
"false").schema(schema).csv("C:\\vikas\\spark\\Interview\\text.txt")
dfWithSchema.show()
```

### using sql context

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext

val fileRdd = 
sc.textFile("C:\\vikas\\spark\\Interview\\text.txt").map(_.split(",")).map{x 
=> org.apache.spark.sql.Row(x:_*)}
val sqlDf = sqlCtx.createDataFrame(fileRdd,schema)
sqlDf.show()
```

Answer (score 8):

If you want to use the `toDF` method, you have to convert your `RDD` of `Array[String]` into a `RDD` of a case class. For example, you have to do:

```
case class Test(id:String,filed2:String)
val myFile = sc.textFile("file.txt")
val df= myFile.map( x => x.split(";") ).map( x=> Test(x(0),x(1)) ).toDF()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Mark. It should have a green tick but Tzach had similar answer just a fraction of second before and I ended up accepting his solution. +1 for your help.

Answer (score 3):

You will not able to convert it into data frame until you use implicit conversion.

```
val sqlContext = new SqlContext(new SparkContext())

import sqlContext.implicits._
```

After this only you can convert this to data frame

```
case class Test(id:String,filed2:String)

val myFile = sc.textFile("file.txt")

val df= myFile.map( x => x.split(";") ).map( x=> Test(x(0),x(1)) ).toDF()
```

Comment: This was the key, it is nowhere explicitly documented.

Comment: Its not directly mentioned but you can find reference here .. https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/sql-programming-guide.html

Answer (score 1):

```
val df = spark.read.textFile("abc.txt")

case class Abc (amount:Int, types: String, id:Int)  //columns and data types

val df2 = df.map(rec=>Amount(rec(0).toInt, rec(1), rec(2).toInt))
rdd2.printSchema
```

---

```
root
 |-- amount: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- types: string (nullable = true)
 |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 1):

A txt File with PIPE (|) delimited file can be read as :

---

```
df = spark.read.option("sep", "|").option("header", "true").csv("s3://bucket_name/folder_path/file_name.txt")
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I am quite late to answer this but I have come up with a different answer:

```
val rdd = sc.textFile("/home/training/mydata/file.txt")

val text = rdd.map(lines=lines.split(",")).map(arrays=>(ararys(0),arrays(1))).toDF("id","name").show
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read a file to have an RDD and then assign schema to it. Two common ways to creating schema are either using a case class or a Schema object [my preferred one]. Follows the quick snippets of code that you may use.

**Case Class approach**

```
case class Test(id:String,name:String)
val myFile = sc.textFile("file.txt")
val df= myFile.map( x => x.split(";") ).map( x=> Test(x(0),x(1)) ).toDF()
```

**Schema Approach**

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
val schemaString = "id name"
val fields = schemaString.split(" ").map(fieldName => StructField(fieldName, StringType, nullable=true))
val schema = StructType(fields)

val dfWithSchema = sparkSess.read.option("header","false").schema(schema).csv("file.txt")
dfWithSchema.show()
```

The second one is my preferred approach since case class has a limitation of max 22 fields and this will be a problem if your file has more than 22 fields!